# error: cannot find symbol - stream().toArray(String[]::new);

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am new to Java, I got exercise:
Given an array of strings, return another array containing all of its longest strings.

so I wrote code:

```
String[] allLongestStrings(String[] inputArray) {

int longest = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) 
{
    if (inputArray[i].length() > longest) 
    {
        longest = inputArray[i].length();
    }
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int j = 0; j < inputArray.length; j++)
{
    String word = inputArray[i];
    if(word.length() == longest) list.add(word);
}
}
String[] strings = list.stream().toArray(String[]::new);
return strings; }
```

but I recive error:

```
file.java on line 20: error: cannot find symbol
String[] strings = list.stream().toArray(String[]::new);
                   ^ symbol:   variable list   location: class _runzzmqt 1 error
```

Any tips? I dont need solution, just a hint.

Thank you.

Comment: what exactly you are trying `list.stream().toArray(String[]::new)` ?

Comment: I cannot return ArrayList, it have to be String[] array

Comment: Indent your code properly, and the problem will be obvious. You're shooting yourself in the foot by not indenting. You can't figure out the structure and the scope of variables anymore.

Comment: The main reason you're getting this error is as a result of poor indentation and general code formatting.. It's a scope issue and it'd have been more visible if you formatted properly.

Comment: just to complete, the error means that the `list` is not declared (at that line), **nothing** related to `stream().toArray...` as suggested by title)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got scope issues here.

list been declared inside for loop and you are trying to access it outside.

Remember that scope is restricted to block (`{}`). If you have indent the code, you can see that easily

```
       for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
            if (inputArray[i].length() > longest) {
                longest = inputArray[i].length();
            }
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int j = 0; j < inputArray.length; j++) {
                String word = inputArray[i];
                if (word.length() == longest)
                    list.add(word);
            }
        }
        String[] strings = list.stream().toArray(String[]::new);
```

Just move it to top and you'd able to access it.

```
String[] allLongestStrings(String[] inputArray) {

        int longest = 0;

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
            if (inputArray[i].length() > longest) {
                longest = inputArray[i].length();
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < inputArray.length; j++) {
                String word = inputArray[i];
                if (word.length() == longest)
                    list.add(word);
            }
        }
        String[] strings = list.stream().toArray(String[]::new);
        return strings;
    }
```

Comment: Correct.. You beat me to it!

Answer (score 0):

Your list declaration is inside of a loop, so it's not visible outside. You need to either move the list declaration outside of the loop

```
   String[] allLongestStrings(String[] inputArray) {

        int longest = 0;

       List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
        if (inputArray[i].length() > longest) {
            longest = inputArray[i].length();
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < inputArray.length; j++) { 
            list.clean();// if there is longer String, remove previous results 
            String word = inputArray[i];
            if (word.length() == longest)
                list.add(word);
        }
    }
    String[] strings = list.stream().toArray(String[]::new);
    return strings;
}
```

You can also use Stream API to bigger expense:

```
 String[] allLongestStrings(String[] inputArray) {

    int longest = Arrays.stream(inputArray)
            .map(String::length)
            .max(Integer::compareTo).orElse(0);

    return Arrays.stream(inputArray)
            .filter( v-> v.length() == longest)
            .toArray(String[]::new);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others, you're facing a ***scope*** issue, therefore you need to declare the `ArrayList` outside the loops.

However, there's another issue; so in order to find all the longest strings of a particular size you'll need to remove the nested loops into two individual distinct loops like this:

```
String[] allLongestStrings(String[] inputArray) {

        int longest = 0;
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++)
        {
            if (inputArray[i].length() > longest)
            {
                longest = inputArray[i].length();
            }

        }


        for(int j = 0; j < inputArray.length; j++)
        {
            String word = inputArray[j];
            if(word.length() == longest) list.add(word);
        }

        String[] strings = list.toArray(new String[0]);
        return strings;
}
```

This is necessary because the code you've shown in your post *is not* iterating over the entire array to find the longest string prior to doing the comparison with the elements and thus leading to wrong results.

Also, no need to create a `Stream` from the list in order to convert it into an array, simply do `list.toArray(new String[0]);`